# Finding the expected value of $\dfrac{X}{Y}$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Below is a problem I did. I believe I did it correctly and I am hoping that somebody here can either confirm that I did it right or tell me where I went wrong.

Problem:
Let $X$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[1,2]$. Let $Y$ be a random variable that is uniformly distributed on the interval $[1,2]$. Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, what is
$E\left( \dfrac{X}{Y}\right) $?

Answer:

The density function of $X$ and $Y$ is the same. It is:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{for } 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
\begin{align*}
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \dfrac{x}{y} \,\, dy \, dx \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \int_1^2 x \ln (y) \Big|_1^2 \,\, dy \, dx \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \int_1^2 x \ln (2) - x \ln (1) \, dx \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \int_1^2 \ln (2) \, x \, dx \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \dfrac{ \ln (2) \, x^2}{2} \Big|_1^2 \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \dfrac{ 4 \ln (2) }{2} - \dfrac{ \ln (2) }{2} \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &= \dfrac{ 3 \ln (2) }{2} \\
E\left(  \dfrac{X}{Y} \right)  &\doteq 1.0397208 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Looks good to me. I would use $\approx$ at the end.

Comment: Looks good.  OK!!!!!

Comment: If somebody could post there comment as an answer, I could accept the question and close it. Thank you.

Comment: @Bob, you can click `Edit`, copy-paste your own work as an answer. (It's permissible on this site to answer your own question.)

Comment: Style comment: it's nice to just write $$E\biggl( \frac{X}{Y} \biggr) = {}$$ once, and on each subsequent line to just begin with ${}={}$, so the entire calculation looks like a chain of equalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I confirm that your calculation is correct.

The key step is to identify the [joint density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) $g(x,y)$ of $X$ and $Y$. Since they are idenpendent, you simply have
$$
g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)=1_{[1,2]\times[1,2]}(x,y)\;.
$$
You implicitly use it in the first step of your calculation. To simplify the calculation, you may also separate the double integral as
$$
\int_1^2xdx\int_1^2\frac1ydy\;=\frac32\cdot\ln(2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer looks perfect to me! I did a quick numerical simulation and it agrees with you.

```
>> b = 1 + rand(1000000,1);
>> a = 1 + rand(1000000,1);
>> mean(a./b)

ans =

    1.0396
```

Comment: Yes, so this is a numerical approximation that supports the answer, but it looks like the OP was trying to calculate the expected value *exactly* in order to practice the techniques.

Comment: You are exactly right! this is just to add a bit of confidence to it. No need to vote